# adding values to multidimensional aray in PHP

Tags: php

I have array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Open Projects] => Row 1
            [Owner] => Owner
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Open Projects] => Row 2
            [Owner] => Owner
        )

)
```

I need to get

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Open Projects] => Row 1
            [Owner] => Owner
            [Text] => Row 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Open Projects] => Row 2
            [Owner] => Owner
            [Text] => Row 2
        )

)
```

This is my code:

```
$columnsamplearray  =(array)$colarray["columnssample"];  
foreach($columnsamplearray as $sampleval) {
    $newValue=(array) $newColumns[$sampleval]." =>Row1";
}
array_push($columnsamplearray,$newValue);
```

Here  `$columnsamplearray`  is getting my whole array. `$newValue` contains my newly added text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `foreach` assigning the current element's key to the `$key` variable on each iteration. Then you can add the desired value key to the right `array`.

```
foreach($columnsamplearray as $key => $value) {
    $columnsamplearray[$key]->text = 'Row 1';
}
```

Comment: getting error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array.because this is a nested array.here $value is another array.may this error occur

Comment: Try `$columnsamplearray[$key]->text = 'Row 1';` then

Comment: Thanks its working when i added the  $columnsamplearray[$key]->text = 'Row 1';

Comment: $columnsamplearray  =(array)$colarray["columnssample"];  
              foreach($columnsamplearray as $key => $value) {
                $columnsamplearray[$key]->$newColumns = 'Row 1';
              }
              $arrTemplate[$index]['columnssample']=$columnsamplearray;                   I Have tried liked this.its solved

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_map to apply a function to all of the members of the array:

```
function addText($item) {
    $item['text'] = $item['Open Projects'];
    return $item;
}

$result = array_map("addText", $columnsamplearray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array with objects. You are trying to reach that object properties in array's way. That is not going to work.

Instead, try to reach each object and then reach their desired properties:

```
foreach ($array as $object) {
    $object->property = 'text';
}
```